# display fieldname and value of sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list,

and want to get all the items of that list and and loop through each field of each item to  output someting like:

"fieldname: value"

how can i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Johan was close, but didn't have the actual value.  The following should do:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("<site_url_where_list_is>"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["<list_name>"];
        foreach (SPListItem listItem in list.Items)
        {
            foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
            {
                object value = listItem[field.Id];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(field.Title + ": " + (value == null ? "(null)" : value.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you would normally not call SPList.Items unless you want to iterate over all the records.  Instead you would use SPList.GetItems(SPQuery).

Comment: Great of you to mention that we shouldn´t use SPList.Items but instead SPList.GetItems Kirk...that is way important on big collections...I know from experience. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
    SPList list = GetList();

    foreach(SPListItem item in list.Items)
    {
      foreach (SPField field in item.Fields)
      {

        Console.WriteLine("Name : {0} - Value: {1}", 
                          field.InternalName, item[field.Id].ToString());
      }
    }
```

something like that??

**EDIT:** Fixed my code error after Kirk mentioning it.